# jQuery - el.val(!e.val()) returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form element that I'd like to toggle the value of between 1 and 0, on a click event.

I know that I can store this value and test it, to determine the new value for the field.

My question is though, why doesn't the following work?

```
$('#myEl').val(!$('#myEl').val());
```

Comment: Could you post the rest of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`val()` returns a string, and `!` returns a boolean, which converted to string (by `val(...)`) becomes "false".

Instead convert the string to number, and the boolean to number, using the unary `+` twice:

```js
$("#toggle").click(function () {
    $('#myEl').val(+!+$('#myEl').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myEl" value="1">
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because #myEl has a value, by doing `$('#myEl').val(!$('#myEl').val());` you are setting #myEl as false.